# TCLAP custom args in c++

Tags: c++, parsing, command-line

I want to make custom cmd params with [TCLAP](http://tclap.sourceforge.net/)
i want the following syntax for this
`file.exe -a -b <string> <string>`
`file.exe -c <string>`
how can i do it?

Comment: The best TCLAP can offer would be multivalue args that look like `file.exe -a <string> -a <string>`.

Comment: can you please edit your question, its confusing